# snap remove errors out as cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory

Tags: snap, raspberrypi

This is the error I get:

```
╰─○ sudo snap remove chromium
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Disconnect chromium:chromium-config from core:personal-files (cannot update mount namespace of snap "chromium": cannot update preserved namespace of snap "chromium":
-----
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/tmp/.X11-unix /tmp/.X11-unix none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/themes/elementary /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/themes/elementary none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/themes/Yaru /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/themes/Yaru none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/themes/Yaru-light /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/themes/Yaru-light none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/themes/Yaru-dark /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/themes/Yaru-dark none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/themes/Radiant-MATE /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/themes/Radiant-MATE none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/themes/Radiance /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/themes/Radiance none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/themes/Materia /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/themes/Materia none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/themes/Materia-light /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/themes/Materia-light none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/themes/Materia-light-compact /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/themes/Materia-light-compact none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/themes/Materia-dark /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/themes/Materia-dark none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/themes/Materia-dark-compact /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/themes/Materia-dark-compact none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/themes/Materia-compact /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/themes/Materia-compact none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/themes/Matcha-sea /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/themes/Matcha-sea none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/themes/Matcha-dark-sea /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/themes/Matcha-dark-sea none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/themes/Matcha-dark-azul /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/themes/Matcha-dark-azul none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/themes/Matcha-dark-aliz /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/themes/Matcha-dark-aliz none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/themes/Matcha-azul /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/themes/Matcha-azul none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/themes/Matcha-aliz /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/themes/Matcha-aliz none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/themes/HighContrast /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/themes/HighContrast none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/themes/Greybird /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/themes/Greybird none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/themes/Greybird-dark /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/themes/Greybird-dark none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/themes/Communitheme /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/themes/Communitheme none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/themes/Communitheme-light /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/themes/Communitheme-light none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/themes/Communitheme-dark /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/themes/Communitheme-dark none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/themes/Breeze /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/themes/Breeze none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/themes/Breeze-Dark /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/themes/Breeze-Dark none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/themes/Arc /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/themes/Arc none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/themes/Arc-Darker /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/themes/Arc-Darker none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/themes/Arc-Dark /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/themes/Arc-Dark none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/themes/Ambiant-MATE /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/themes/Ambiant-MATE none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/themes/Ambiant-MATE-Dark /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/themes/Ambiant-MATE-Dark none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/themes/Ambiance /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/themes/Ambiance none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/themes/Adwaita /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/themes/Adwaita none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/themes/Adwaita-dark /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/themes/Adwaita-dark none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/sounds/freedesktop /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/sounds/freedesktop none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/sounds/communitheme /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/sounds/communitheme none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/sounds/Yaru /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/sounds/Yaru none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/whiteglass /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/whiteglass none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/ubuntu-mono-light none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/redglass /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/redglass none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/hicolor /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/hicolor none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/handhelds /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/handhelds none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/elementary /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/elementary none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/elementary-xfce /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/elementary-xfce none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/elementary-xfce-darkest /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/elementary-xfce-darkest none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/elementary-xfce-darker /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/elementary-xfce-darker none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/elementary-xfce-dark /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/elementary-xfce-dark none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/default /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/default none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/communitheme /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/communitheme none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/breeze_cursors /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/breeze_cursors none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/Yaru /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/Yaru none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/Suru /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/Suru none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/Radiant-MATE /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/Radiant-MATE none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/Papirus-Maia /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/Papirus-Maia none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/Papirus-Light-Maia /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/Papirus-Light-Maia none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/Papirus-Dark-Maia /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/Papirus-Dark-Maia none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/Papirus-Adapta-Nokto-Maia /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/Papirus-Adapta-Nokto-Maia none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/Papirus-Adapta-Maia /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/Papirus-Adapta-Maia none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/Humanity /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/Humanity none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/Humanity-Dark /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/Humanity-Dark none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/HighContrast /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/HighContrast none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/DMZ-White /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/DMZ-White none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/DMZ-Black /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/DMZ-Black none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/Breeze_Snow /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/Breeze_Snow none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/Ambiant-MATE /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/Ambiant-MATE none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/Adwaita /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/Adwaita none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/Adwaita /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/Adwaita none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/Ambiant-MATE /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/Ambiant-MATE none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/Breeze_Snow /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/Breeze_Snow none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/DMZ-Black /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/DMZ-Black none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/DMZ-White /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/DMZ-White none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/HighContrast /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/HighContrast none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/Humanity-Dark /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/Humanity-Dark none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/Humanity /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/Humanity none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/Papirus-Adapta-Maia /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/Papirus-Adapta-Maia none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/Papirus-Adapta-Nokto-Maia /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/Papirus-Adapta-Nokto-Maia none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/Papirus-Dark-Maia /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/Papirus-Dark-Maia none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/Papirus-Light-Maia /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/Papirus-Light-Maia none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/Papirus-Maia /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/Papirus-Maia none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/Radiant-MATE /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/Radiant-MATE none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/Suru /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/Suru none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/Yaru /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/Yaru none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/breeze_cursors /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/breeze_cursors none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/communitheme /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/communitheme none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/default /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/default none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/elementary-xfce-dark /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/elementary-xfce-dark none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/elementary-xfce-darker /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/elementary-xfce-darker none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/elementary-xfce-darkest /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/elementary-xfce-darkest none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/elementary-xfce /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/elementary-xfce none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/elementary /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/elementary none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/handhelds /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/handhelds none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/hicolor /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/hicolor none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/redglass /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/redglass none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/ubuntu-mono-light none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/icons/whiteglass /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons/whiteglass none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/icons": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/sounds/Yaru /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/sounds/Yaru none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/sounds": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/sounds/communitheme /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/sounds/communitheme none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/sounds": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519/share/sounds/freedesktop /snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/sounds/freedesktop none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1933/data-dir/sounds": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
cannot update snap namespace: cannot create writable mimic over "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
-----)
```

I removed /tmp/.snap and created it again with sudo `mkdir /tmp/.snap` , same error.

Here is the distribution details:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 21.10 Release: 21.10 Codename: impish
```

here is the uname details:

```
╭─behlul at behlul-raspberrypi400 in ~ 22-03-18 - 18:48:34
╰─○ uname -a
Linux behlul-raspberrypi400 5.13.0-1020-raspi #22-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Mon Mar 7 13:09:05 UTC 2022 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

How can I fix this issue and remove packages again?

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? If so, which version and flavour?

Comment: Lol the uname output didn't get copied. Here you go: `Linux behlul-raspberrypi400 5.13.0-1020-raspi #22-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Mon Mar 7 13:09:05 UTC 2022 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: It is the ubuntu build that is installed with the raspberry pi imager.

Comment: Please provide OS & release details; kernel details does not provide an answer to that question.

Comment: ╰─○ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.10
Release:        21.10
Codename:       impish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was because of some folder being removed in /tmp. Rebooting fixes the issue (not sure if logout would fix too).